# URL assigned to iframe by Javascript does not load properly

Tags: javascript

**What I am trying to achieve**
I am trying to load a cookie from Website A in the background as a 1 x 1 pixel followed by redirecting users to Website B.

**Problem**
In the code below, users are redirected to Website B. However, it does not appear that Website A was loading in the background as I could not see the Website A cookie in the browser.

How can I solve this?

Thank you

```html
<html>
  <META name="description" HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="">
  <iframe id="MyFrame" style="width: 1px; height: 1px;"></iframe>
</html>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

    var tidParameter = urlParams.get("tid");
    var offerParameter = urlParams.get("offer");
    console.log (offerParameter);

    if (offerParameter == "bb") {
      var address = "www.websiteA.com/?tid=";
      var combined = address + tidParameter;
      var iframeSrcValue = document.getElementById("MyFrame").src;
      document.getElementById('MyFrame').setAttribute("src", combined);
      document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').setAttribute("content", "5;url=www.websiteB.com");
    }
    else if (offerParameter == "bd") {
      document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').setAttribute("content", "5;url=https://www.google.com");
    }
    else {
      document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').setAttribute("content", "5;url=https://www.hotmail.com");
    }
  });
</script>
```

**What confuses me**
When I try the code in this manner, it works (ie. redirects to Website B and cookie from Website A loads). Unclear to me why the addition of the if, else if causes the problem?

```
<html>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="5;url=www.websiteB.com">
<iframe id="MyFrame" style="width: 1px; height: 1px;"></iframe>
</html>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
var mainParameter = urlParams.get('tid');
var address = "www.websiteA.com/?tid=";
var combined = address + mainParameter;
console.log(combined);
var iframeSrcValue = document.getElementById("MyFrame").src;
document.getElementById('MyFrame').setAttribute("src", combined);
});
<script>
```

Comment: Yea, you can't access a website's cookies by embedding that website in an iframe...

Comment: Thanks @Cerbrus, then would you be able to see what's wrong with my code? I have added a delay to the redirect too to make sure the pixel has time to load.

Comment: Is it safe to omit the scheme from a URL? `www.websiteB.com` vs `https://www.websiteB.com`

Comment: @spender I have gone back to check my code an they all have `https://www.` in front of them.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the pixel has time to load. You _can not_ access cookies of websites you load into an iframe.